# EC has lower CPU consumption than RSA under what condition?

Tags: elliptic-curves, cpu

When I searched Google, [the top result](https://avinetworks.com/docs/latest/ecc-versus-rsa-certificate-priority/) said

> On average, processing for ECC is about four times less CPU-intensive than for RSA.

Yeah, but under what condition? The page says  "A 256-bit EC certificate (the minimum length supported) is roughly equivalent to a 3k RSA cert. " Then, does the above 1/4 consumption mean a situation like 256-bit EC vs 3K RSA, which is "roughly equivalent" security? Also, don't modern CPU's have some sort of hardware acceleration for RSA? Does the above assume when the encryption is done purely on software, without using such hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> under what condition (is processing for ECC about four times less CPU-intensive than for RSA) ?

That figure is likely for *computing and **once** verifying* a signature at an industry-standard security level, that is 256-bit ECC and 2048 or 3072-bit RSA (or almost equivalently, encrypting and decrypting once a small message, at such level). And that *"about four times"* figure is conservative: the actual ratio is often bigger (esp. for 3072-bit RSA).

That comparison would be very different, and much in favor of RSA, if verifying the signature was performed much more often than computing the signature†. That's because with common parameters, RSA is much faster (by a factor like 40, sometime much more) at signature verification (or encryption) than at signature generation (or decryption). That's one of the reasons RSA is still very much used to sign public key certificates, because the signature of these is made once, verified many times (another reason is that RSA was first, and now is entrenched when it comes to that functionality; yet another is that RSA is simpler, thus less likely to be wrongly implemented).

> Also, don't modern CPU's have some sort of hardware acceleration for RSA?

Whatever acceleration (dedicated instruction‡ or co-processor<sup>*</sup>) they have for RSA most often also is usable for the dominant breeds of ECC: Elliptic Curve on prime field $\mathbb F_p$ (e.g. [secp256r1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.2) or [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.1)).

> Does the above assume when the encryption is done purely on software, without using such hardware acceleration?

I can't tell; but it does not make so much of a difference on the ratio for RSA vs ECC. On servers, crypto tasks sometime are offloaded  to an HSM, e.g. a dedicated PCIe card. [Here is one](https://www.entrust.com/-/media/documentation/datasheets/entrust-nshield-solo-ds.pdf) which I'm told is hardware-accelerated. It's rated at 14400 signatures/s for ECC-256, 8600 signatures/s for RSA-2048, 2025 signatures/s for RSA-4096. This reasonably corroborates the factor of four in the source, at conjectured equivalent security level (which would be closer to RSA-3072 than RSA-2048).

---

† or if encryption was much more common than decryption, as could be the case for individually encrypted audit log entries that are seldom used.

‡ Taking the example of x86-64 CPUs, according to [this source](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-ipp-crypto-multi-buffer-acceleration.html)

> In 2014, the ADX extension was implemented on the Broadwell microarchitecture. This extension consists of ADCX and ADOX instructions and together with MULX instruction implemented earlier are using in context of multi-precision arithmetic implementations. So, for example, till now the best OpenSSL* public key implementations are based on MULX with accompanied instructions ADCX and ADOX.

<sup>*</sup> For an example of a CPU with dedicated crypto accelerator, see [this](https://www.ssi.gouv.fr/uploads/2020/07/cible-anssi-cc-2020_30.pdf#page=15)

Comment: Do you have any source on there being *any* acceleration present for RSA/ECC in modern x86? The instruction set and it's extension is *massive*, but I am only aware of `AES-NI`, which aims to accelerate AES. Which makes sense, considering that asymmetric cryptography in TLS is afaik only used to establish the ephemeral AES key. To clarify, I'm asking about RSA/ECC specific instructions, not general instructions which also help in these particular case, like [this OpenJDK issue](https://openjdk.org/jeps/246)

Comment: @jaskij: there are instructions added to the x86-64 with the intention of accelerating RSA and ECC; I added a reference, see note ‡ in the answer. I'm told there's also VPCLMULQDQ in AVX-512 that can be put to good use in crypto, though I have never used it, and I can't be sure the intention was crypto acceleration. In the OpenJDK case, I think "the pure software-based implementation" refers to something using legacy Java libraries like the original bigint, which s**ks big times when it comes to crypto, on speed and security.

Comment: @jaskij: The core problem in RSA is bigint multiply.  x86 doesn't have RSA-specific instructions beyond mulx and adcx/adox, which are useful in general for any bigint multiply of more than 2 register-widths.  (Or possibly if there are other cases where you'd want to overlap the work of two bigint adds, interleaving two dependency chains; that's how ADX wins vs. traditional `adc` for bigint multiply, in finding parallelism in adding partial products.) 
 (https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-large-integer-arithmetic-paper.pdf)

Comment: @fgrieu: carryless multiply support in x86 goes back to 2nd-gen Nehalem (Westmere) in 2010, for regular [PCLMULQDQ](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pclmulqdq).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLMUL_instruction_set.  It gives you a single 64x64 => 128-bit product, with the immediate selecting which half of each 128-bit input register to actually use.  (So 4 different possibilities, low x low, or a cross product, or high x high). The AVX-512 version (Ice Lake) does 2x or 4x of this in parallel (not a single wider multiply).  There's also a non-AVX512 VPCLMUL for 256-bit, e.g. in Alder Lake.

Comment: PCLMUL has many use-cases, including GCM for block ciphers, but also CRC, and maybe RAID6 or other Galois Field stuff.  Also generic bithacks, e.g. carryless-multiply of a number by itself spaces out the bits, useful for interleaving the bits of two integers.  Intel did later introduce GFNI, Galois Field new insns, probably speeding up RAID6 and other error-correction-code use cases more. ([What are the AVX-512 Galois-field-related instructions for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59124720) / https://builders.intel.com/docs/networkbuilders/galois-field-new-instructions-gfni-technology-guide.pdf)

Comment: GF2P8AFFINEQB (Ice Lake and low-power Tremont) is also useful as an arbitrary bit-permuation (within bytes), e.g. reversing the bits of an integer when used along with a byte-shuffle: https://wunkolo.github.io/post/2020/11/gf2p8affineqb-bit-reversal/.  https://gist.github.com/animetosho/d3ca95da2131b5813e16b5bb1b137ca0 lists other fun uses, like bit-matrix multiplication.